# Override view view field twig drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I have to override this template for my view:
`views-view-fields.html.twig`

My view name: **banner_bim**
My view block name: **Block_1**

I tried with:

1. `views-view-field--banner_bim.html.twig`
2. `views-view-field--banner_bim--page.html.twig`
3. `views-view-field--banner-bim.html.twig`
4. `views-view-field--banner-bim--page.html.twig`

None of these templates override base field template.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The correct one was:

views-view-field--banner_bim.html.twig

The problem was not the name of the file, but the cache.

I deleted the "Render cache" but it was necessary to clear the entire cache to see the change.